# how to set hikari connection properties in datasource.groovy

Tags: grails, hikaricp

In springboot2.X i am able to set hikari connection pool config like maxLifeTime in application.ymal easily.
Similarly i want to to it in groovy. Is it inside dBProperties?
i am using groovy 2.5.4 and grails 2.4.4

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    type = "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
    properties {
    ....
    ....
    dbProperties {
       maxLifeTime=200000
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as bean in `conf/spring/resources.groovy`

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import grails.util.Holders

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    dataSource(HikariDataSource) { bean ->
        def ds = Holders.config.dataSource

        def hp = new Properties()
        hp.username = ds.username
        hp.password = ds.password
        hp.jdbcUrl = ds.url
        hp.driverClassName = ds.driverClassName

        hp.connectionTimeout = ds.hikariConnectionTimeout
        hp.maximumPoolSize = ds.hikariMaximumPoolSize
        hp.maxLifetime = ds.hikariMaxLifetime
        hp.idleTimeout = ds.hikariIdleTimeout
        hp.minimumIdle = ds.hikariMinimumIdle
        hp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"

        HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(hp)
        bean.constructorArgs = [hc]
    }
}
```

With these added you can define your properties in your `Datasoure.groovy` like this

```
dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
            username = "username"
            password = "password"

            hikariMinimumIdle = 5
            hikariMaximumPoolSize = 30
            hikariIdleTimeout = 600000
            hikariConnectionTimeout = 30000
            hikariMaxLifetime = 1800000
        }
```